# Prevent ipython from storing outputs in Out variable

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I'm currently working with pandas and ipython. Since pandas dataframes are copied when you perform operations with it, my memory usage increases by 500 mb with every cell. I believe it's because the data gets stored in the `Out` variable, since this doesn't happen with the default python interpreter.

How do I disable the `Out` variable?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code? I thought operations could be either `inplace=True` or not...

Comment: @IanS I'm using operators like `+, /` etc. Even if I'm not, I'd rather not use `infile` for everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first option you have is to avoid producing output. If you don't really need to *see* the intermediate results just avoid them and put all the computations in a single cell.

If you need to actually display that data you can use `InteractiveShell.cache_size` option to set a maximum size for the cache. Setting this value to `0` disables caching.

To do so you have to create a file called `ipython_config.py` (or `ipython_notebook_config.py`) under your `~/.ipython/profile_default` directory with the contents:

```
c = get_config()

c.InteractiveShell.cache_size = 0
```

After that you'll see:

```
In [1]: 1
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: Out[1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d74cffe9cfe3> in <module>()
----> 1 Out[1]

KeyError: 1
```

You can also create different profiles for ipython using the command `ipython profile create <name>`. This will create a new profile under `~/.ipython/profile_<name>` with a default configuration file. You can then launch ipython using the `--profile <name>` option to load that profile.

Alternatively you can use the [`%reset out`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-reset) magic to reset the output cache or use the [`%xdel`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-xdel) magic to delete a specific object:

```
In [1]: 1
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: 2
Out[2]: 2

In [3]: %reset out

Once deleted, variables cannot be recovered. Proceed (y/[n])? y
Flushing output cache (2 entries)

In [4]: Out[1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d74cffe9cfe3> in <module>()
----> 1 Out[1]

KeyError: 1

In [5]: 1
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: 2
Out[6]: 2

In [7]: v = Out[5]

In [8]: %xdel v    # requires a variable name, so you cannot write %xdel Out[5]

In [9]: Out[5]     # xdel removes the value of v from Out and other caches
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-573c4eba9654> in <module>()
----> 1 Out[5]

KeyError: 5
```

Comment: You say you're having trouble using the cache_size setting - where are you trying to set it? That is an IPython config option, not a Jupyter config option, so it still goes under `~/.ipython/profile_default/`.

Comment: @ThomasK I tried using the `%config` magic and passing the option `--InteractiveShell.cache_size=0` from the command line. I know that you can create profiles, but I believe there must be at least a way to do this without having to create one or change the default profile. Anyway if that's the only way I will edit it in the answer.

Comment: You can set it temporarily with the `%config` magic or the command line option. Setting it permanently requires doing so in a profile.

Comment: @ThomasK Yeah, the problem is that using `%config` and the command line option doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Oh, right. It might be something that only has an effect when the application is starting.

Comment: You can use `%reset -f in out`. It looks like `_` is classified under the "in" category, even if it's an output, and you could want to remove it.