# Ignoring large returned values in IPython

Tags: python, memory, garbage-collection, ipython

While profiling functions in IPython, I often face a situation like

```
In[1]:  fun() # returns large object (tuple of numpy arrays)
Out[1]: #values of large object printed here
In[2]:  fun() # should return another large object of the same size
Out[2]: MemoryError
```

The `MemoryError` must occur after In[2] because IPython stores a reference to the returned object in `Out[1],` and there is not enough room for a second object of the same size in memory. So I try `del Out` and then `gc.collect()` and call fun again. The memory error still occurs, presumably because IPython has a reference to the output somewhere.

One piece of evidence for this is that the memory usage of IPython as reported by gnu top is not reduced after deletion and garbage collection. It is also possible that the memory of the large object is in fact freed internally, but CPython chooses not to return the memory to the operating system, so gnu top does not detect the change. I am not sure how to test for this--it would make the MemoryError much more mysterious.

One solution I tested is to write a wrapper function so that the return value is ignored, but this is more work than I would like to do when calling a function in an interactive session.

Is there a way to get ipython to truly ignore (some/all) return values so that the memory is not locked down when I don't need it? Or is this a different issue altogether?

As for the suggested duplicate: [Prevent ipython from storing outputs in Out variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808904/prevent-ipython-from-storing-outputs-in-out-variable) it is indeed related. (And helpful to link to). This question is somewhat different in that my issue is for the IPython terminal, so cell-based solutions apply differently, and I am not looking to suppress all output from all commands necessarily. I am also explicitly wondering about the mechanism that makes deleting Out fail to release the memory. The solution offered in the comments is different from that in the other question and is elegant.

Comment: `fun();` skips the `Out` display and archiving.  The `Out[1]` is also assigned to `_` and later `__` etc.  I also use `len(fun())` or `fun().shape` if I want some info on the returned object, but don't want to see or archive the whole thing.

Comment: This works great! I didn't know about _ and __. I assume they store the most recent outputs? Feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: `_`,`__`, `___` are links to the last 3 `Out` values.